# Nginx cannot find my file path of my CSS and JS after adding the "gzip_static on" in nginx config to decompress the gzipped files

Tags: nginx, static, location, gzip

I used grunt to gzip all the css and javascript files. To decompress, I added the "gzip_static on" line under the "location" brackets in nginx config.
So It has to find style.css.gz If the webpage requests to load style.css. But It throws the error as the 404 Not Found for all the css and js files.

```
location ~* \.(css)$
{ 
  gzip_static on;
  root /file/to/path/stylesheets;
}
location ~* \.(js)$
{
  gzip_static on;
  root /file/to/path/javascripts;
}
```